# Plotting multiple series on a line graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, series

Can someone please help me, i am trying to plot multiple lines on a single graph. There is a function which calls on different pandas series to be plotted in a figure. The code print the figures separately, how do i make the lines so that they all are plotted in a single graph?

```
def plot_genregraph(genrerank):
 transposed_series = genrerank.set_index('Genre').transpose()
 print(transposed_series)
 return transposed_series

plt.figure(figsize = (30, 30)) 
 for title in rankingsys_title:
 plot_genregraph(all_rankgenre.loc[all_rankgenre['Genre'] == title]).plot(marker='o')
 plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (30, 30))`, then `plot_genregraph(all_rankgenre.loc[all_rankgenre['Genre'] == title]).plot(marker='o', ax=ax)`. Make sure `plt.show()` is outside the loop.

Comment: @BigBen i have tried to put the plt.show() outside the loop but to no avail :(

Comment: You need to also fix the `ax` portion...

Comment: @BigBen could you please advice on how i could do that? thank you in advance

Comment: Did you gloss over the first sentence in the first comment?

Comment: @BigBen hi sir, im terribly sorry i missed out on the ax part. Thank you so much for your help!